# Using body parser and dicer for multipart uploads with express js 4

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express 4 with body-parser like so

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

When I added [dicer](https://github.com/mscdex/dicer) it's like body parser stops working.  I no longer have any post params in `req.params` or `req.body` or `req.query`.

Is there a way to use body parser manually?  Does body parser check for multipart forms data and just do nothing ... assume another lib will handle it?

Also, I feel I should note, that I am using dicer to parse the multipart form data for a reason and I don't want to use busboy or multer or xyz if possible.

Comment: Care to share *what* the reason is for using dicer?

Comment: Speed and the low level control I have over it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "Is there a way to use body-parser manually?"
the answer is yes and it is the recommended way of using it. Referring to the [body-parser documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific):

> ## express route-specific
>
> This example demonstrates adding body parsers specifically to the routes that need them. In general, this is the most recommend way to use body-parser with express.

(I added some semi-colons because they would keep me up at night)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username);
})

// POST /api/users gets JSON bodies
app.post('/api/users', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  // create user in req.body
})
```

So depending on which routes you need body-parser for, you can implement it with some custom middleware. Now, **I have not tested this**, but I'm assuming you could also implement it in the same way as other express middleware:

```
// URL encoded bodies
app.use('/api/url/encoded/endpoint', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// JSON encoded bodies
app.use('/api/json/encoded/endpoint', bodyParser.json());
```

Where any routes that match the above endpoints, such as

```
app.use('/api/url/encoded/endpoint/test', function (req, res) { ... });
```

would be parsed using the appropriate middleware as long as they are below the middleware declarations in your code.

To try to answer your whole question, I would say that it would be safe to try not using either parser globally. Keep your parsers api endpoint specific and you shouldn't run into any problems.

**Edit:**

So your question is a little unclear. You would like to use body parser for multipart/form-data? "Body-parser does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature." Again, I haven't tried it but maybe you could give the `bodyParser.raw({ type: ... })` function a try if that's the case. If not, then you need to use dicer in a custom middleware function in which you check for the correct content type.

Comment: I actually tried this and it doesn't work, which is what made me wonder about it ignoring multipart data.

Comment: My response was a little too long for a comment, so I've added it as an edit.